# Is there a way to check if the password in an input element in currently made visible?

Tags: javascript, css, input, show-hide

I am trying to animate something with input of a password element via JS. I want to differentiate between two animations depending on whether or not the password has been made visible by clicking on the standard `::-ms-reveal`  icon. I know that there is a work-around by adding a checkbox to show/hide the password and using `element.type=="password"` in JS instead. Since I would definately prefer the cleaner version without a checkbox, I was hoping to find a solution here.

Unfortunately I have not made much progress so far. Other than the work-around I descibed above, I tried to use the `::-ms-reveal` as a pseudoclass , which unsurprisingly did not work though.

```css
::-ms-reveal {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

input {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: green;
}

input:focus {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: red;
}

input:has(::-ms-reveal:active) {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Type Password here!">
</form>
```

Other than that I did not have a great idea so far.

Comment: `::-ms-reveal` is an obsolete, non standard feature specific to Internet Explorer.  You should be using either the CSS property `display` (an element that is not displayed uses no space), the CSS property `visibility` (an invisible element is still present in the display, but is blank), or the HTML5 attribute `hidden` (effectively the same as CSS `display`)

Comment: `::-ms-reveal` is implemented in Edge as well as IE. It is non-standard, but it is not obsolete. Other browsers are [about to implement](https://www.minitool.com/news/chromium-browsers-reveal-password-001.html) something similar.

Answer (score 1):

A quote from this [WebKit blog post](https://webkit.org/blog/13096/css-has-pseudo-class/#the-basics-of-how-to-use-has-as-a-parent-selector), in the fourth paragraph under the heading **“And more”**:

> Something to note — the CSS Working Group [resolved](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/7463) to disallow all
> existing pseudo-elements inside of `:has()`. For example,
> `article:has(p::first-line)` and `ol:has(li::marker)` won’t work. Same
> with `::before` and `::after`.

So it looks like you’re out of luck, at least for the moment. You can style the `::-ms-reveal` pseudo element itself (the reveal icon/button), but you can’t style the parent `<input>` element based on the state of its pseudo element, using `:has`. Edge assigns the class `.reveal` to the pseudo element after you click it, but the selector `input:has(::-ms-reveal.reveal)` is currently disallowed. `input:has(.reveal)` doesn’t work either, I’ve tried it.

The CSS Working Group might relax this restriction in future, if the [comments in Github](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/7463) are anything to go by. It might be worth waiting until Chrome, Firefox and Safari [provide reveal buttons](https://www.minitool.com/news/chromium-browsers-reveal-password-001.html) in password inputs.